# python json dumps

Tags: python

i have the following string, need to turn it into a list without u'':

```
my_str = "[{u'name': u'squats', u'wrs': [[u'99', 8]], u'id': 2}]"
```

i can get rid of " by using

```
import ast
str_w_quotes = ast.literal_eval(my_str)
```

then i do:

```
import json
json.dumps(str_w_quotes)
```

and get

```
[{\"id\": 2, \"name\": \"squats\", \"wrs\": [[\"55\", 9]]}]
```

Is there a way to get rid of backslashes? the goal is:

```
[{"id": 2, "name": "squats", "wrs": [["55", 9]]}]
```

Comment: `json.dumps` returns `'[{"id": 2, "name": "squats", "wrs": [["99", 8]]}]'` for me.

Comment: Are you sure you are seeing backslashes and not just escaped quotes? For example `"\""` is the same as `'"'`.

Comment: The `u` just indicates it's a unicode string in python < 3.0. Are you sure you want to convert to simple strings?

Comment: You don't get rid of `"`, you're evaluating the string and returning a _list_. `str_w_quotes` is a terrible name for a list

Comment: seems like you are passing `my_str` to json.dumps otherwise `str_w_quotes` comes out without the `u`s like JanneKarila says.

Comment: i had similar results when i unintentionally double-dumped string, like `json.dumps(json.dumps(str))` , check you don't do that guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> "[{\"id\": 2, \"name\": \"squats\", \"wrs\": [[\"55\", 9]]}]".replace('\\"',"\"")
'[{"id": 2, "name": "squats", "wrs": [["55", 9]]}]'
```

note that you could just do this on the original string

```
>>> "[{u'name': u'squats', u'wrs': [[u'99', 8]], u'id': 2}]".replace("u\'","\'")
"[{'name': 'squats', 'wrs': [['99', 8]], 'id': 2}]"
```

Answer (score 21):

This works but doesn't seem too elegant

```
import json
json.dumps(json.JSONDecoder().decode(str_w_quotes))
```

Answer (score 15):

json.dumps thinks that the `"` is part of a the string, not part of the json formatting.

```
import json
json.dumps(json.load(str_w_quotes))
```

should give you:

```
 [{"id": 2, "name": "squats", "wrs": [["55", 9]]}]
```

Comment: it should be `json.loads(json.dumps(str_w_quotes))`

Comment: it works when I tried send blob data to google cloud platform, datastore
 :)

Answer (score 9):

You don't dump your string as JSON, rather you load your string as JSON.

```
import json
json.loads(str_w_quotes)
```

Your string is already in JSON format. You do not want to dump it as JSON again.

Answer (score 2):

```
{"result": "{\\"id\\": 5, \\"macaddr\\": \\"00:11:11:xx:11:D3\\", \\"ip\\": \\"10.46.02.313\\"}'
```

If anybody is getting results like this with `\\`, check if you have called `json.dump` twice on the same output. For me that was the case

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I was working on.

Before I had the return statement as json.dumps(value) and had the \ issue you're facing.  But as the string is already json as yours is, adding this seems to be pointless.  I returned the value and bingo 's gone away.

As for your other requirements I don't know but the \ issue can be fixed like this.

```
    def get(self):
        CPU = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=10, percpu=False)
        CORECOUNT = psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)
        THREADCOUNT = psutil.cpu_count()
        value = {
        "CPU": CPU,
        "CPU_Cores": CORECOUNT,
        "CPU_Threads": THREADCOUNT,
        }
        return value
```